# How detect a MS Windows IP address change without polling

Tags: windows, networking

I am looking for a way to, without polling, to get a notification when the Windows machine IP address change. I need to react to this change and perform some action in my application.

Anyone has done anything of the sort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`NotifyAddrChange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to handle IPv4 address change. The linked page has a succinct demo. [`NotifyIpInterfaceChange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) handles both IPv4 and IPv6 (separately or simultaneously -- see the doc), but requires Vista or later.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET, you can implement the [NetworkChange::NetworkAddressChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkaddresschanged.aspx). I believe that provides exactly what you want.